# Why is global NPM batch file formatted differently from common global packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run a global install of a locally created package.

`npm install -g myModule`

which seems to work.... for the most part.

I see the files I would expect in dir: `Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\` (Windows)

I see a **batch file** and a **cmd** file.

But both have code like: 
`"$basedir/node_modules/myModule/main.js"   "$@"
exit $?`

I look around the dir, and see **Mocha, Bower, Grunt** have something like:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 basedir=`dirname "$0"`

case `uname` in
   *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/bower/bin/bower" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/bower/bin/bower" "$@"
 ret=$? fi exit $ret
```

If I change files to have this format (and adjusts paths) I get the expected behavior (can run `myModule` from command line)....

Otherwise I get error: `... No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

so it turns out this is by design. 
I resolved it by doing the following

1. starting my entry point file with `#!/usr/bin/env node`
   and removing the `.js` extension on the file.
2. setting bin on `package.json` to that file:

   ```
    "bin": {
        "myModule": "bin/myModule"
    }
   ```